# Calling Facebook Messenger API in a synchronous fashion

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, async-await, messenger

I'm using the Facebook Messenger API to create a very basic chatbot. I want to be able to send a series of messages in individual bubbles. However, when I call the API multiple times in the same function. I can't be sure which message will show first. How can I use async/await functionality to correctly order the messages?

Function call initially:

```
const getStartedProcess = async(formattedText,senderID) => {
  const firstMessage = await sendTextMessage(senderID,"First message");
  const secondMessage = await sendTextMessage(senderID,"Second message");
  const thirdMessage = await sendTextMessage(senderID,"Third message");
}
```

Helpers:

```
const sendTextMessage = async(recipientId, messageText) => {
  //format message correctly

  const sent = await callSendAPI(messageData);
  return 0;
}

const callSendAPI = async(messageData) =>{
  request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData

  }, function (error, response, body) {
    //Proccess
    return 0;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
const sendTextMessage = (recipientId, messageText) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //format message correctly
        request({
            uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
            qs: {access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN},
            method: 'POST',
            json: messageData
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(response);
            }
        });
    })
}

const getStartedProcess = async(formattedText, senderID) => {
    try {
        const firstMessage = await sendTextMessage(senderID, 'First message');
        const secondMessage = await sendTextMessage(senderID, 'Second message');
        const thirdMessage = await sendTextMessage(senderID, 'Third message');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add an explanation for your downvote, i am happy to improve my answer. should be fine though.